# Что делает KEY в sql

Tags: mysql, sql, key

Попался мне sql дамп. Вот пример создания таблицы

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_url_alias` (
  `url_alias_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `query` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_alias_id`),
  KEY `query` (`query`),
  KEY `keyword` (`keyword`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;`
```

Какие функции здесь выполняет KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KEY` - это синоним для `INDEX`. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html
Что такое индекс в СУБД, можно почитать в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))